# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I an a stored procedure which selects files with pagination criteria
In this problem, when run this stored procedure, get an exception

```
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation
```

How to works again without above exception?

My researches and tries:

I compared same db on two database servers(prod and test). Test server can work and prod one can not.

I changed connecion string to add "connect timeout=30000" (5 mins)

I also added CommandTimeOut=30000 at file list method.

Additional information: Prod's db server and IIS server placed different server. I searced some articles and because of the slow connection or heavier traffic on db server. But I encountered this error at first time on today.

My stored procedure located below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[inwsDosyaListesiSirali]
@SiteId INT,
@KullaniciId int,
@SubeIp varchar(max),
@DepartmanId int,
@KategoriKod VARCHAR(200)= null,
@Baslik VARCHAR(100) = null,
@IlkTarih DATETIME=null,
@SonTarih DATETIME=null,
@Icerik varchar(max) = null,
@PageNumber INT=1,
@PageSize   INT=10,
@SortColumn varchar(100)=null,
@SortOrder BIT=null
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @KategoriKodListe TABLE(KategoriKod VARCHAR(20)  primary key);

INSERT INTO @KategoriKodListe
SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@KategoriKod,',')

declare @SubeId int,        
        @DepartmanTurId int ,
        @SubeKategoriKod varchar(100)


 SELECT @DepartmanTurId=[DepartmanTurId]  FROM [Departman] 
 where [SiteId]=@SiteId and [Id] = @DepartmanId

 select @SubeId=ks.SubeId, @SubeKategoriKod = ksk.Kod from [dbo].[KurumsalSube] ks 
 inner join  [dbo].[KurumsalSubeKategori] ksk on ks.KategoriId = ksk.KategoriId
 where SiteId=@SiteId and SubeIp like '%'+@SubeIp+'%'         
  ;With EMP AS (
 SELECT 
         r.RaporId
        ,r.HistoryId
        ,r.Baslik
        ,r.DosyaAd
        ,r.RaporAktifTarih
        ,r.RaporGecerlilikTarih
        ,r.RaporTarih
        ,r.KategoriId
        ,h.KayitTarih
        ,r.ParentRaporId
        ,kat.Ad [KategoriAd]
        ,kat.Kod [KategoriKod]
        ,kat.Sira
        ,T.DosyaTurId
        ,T.Ad AS DosyaTurAd
        --,T.Uzanti AS DosyaUzanti
        ,T.iconName
        --,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.[KategoriId] ORDER BY r.[RaporTarih] desc)) AS number
        ,s.SistemDosyaId
        ,s.DosyaAdi as SistemDosyaAd
         FROM Dosya r
        INNER JOIN DosyaKategori kat ON kat.KategoriId=r.KategoriId 
        INNER JOIN DosyaHistory h   ON h.Id=r.HistoryId
        LEFT JOIN DosyaTur T ON T.DosyaTurId=r.DosyaTurId
        LEFT JOIN DosyaIcerik di ON r.SistemDosyaId = di.SistemDosyaId
        --Yetki kontrol kısmı
        left join [dbo].[DosyaYetki] dy on r.DosyaYetkiId = dy.DosyaYetkiId
        LEFT JOIN SistemDosyalari s ON s.SistemDosyaId=r.SistemDosyaId


        WHERE kat.SiteId=@SiteId AND  r.IsOnay=1 
         AND (isnull(@KategoriKod,'') = '' or exists(select 1 from @KategoriKodListe k where k.KategoriKod=kat.Kod)  )
         AND ((NULLIF(r.RaporGecerlilikTarih,'') IS NULL OR (r.RaporGecerlilikTarih >= GETDATE())))
        AND ((NULLIF(r.RaporAktifTarih,'') IS NULL OR (r.RaporAktifTarih <= GETDATE())))
     --   AND ((NULLIF(@Baslik,'') IS NULL OR (r.Baslik like '%'+@Baslik+'%' ) OR NULLIF(r.ParentRaporId,'') IS NOT NULL))
        --AND ((NULLIF(@IlkTarih,'') IS NULL OR (@IlkTarih<=CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day,0,r.RaporTarih)))))
        --AND ((NULLIF(@SonTarih,'') IS NULL OR (@SonTarih>=CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day,0,r.RaporTarih)))))
        --AND ((NULLIF(@Icerik,'') IS NULL OR (di.Icerik like '%'+@Icerik+'%') OR NULLIF(r.ParentRaporId,'') IS NOT NULL))
            --Yetki kontrol kısmı
        and (
        dy.DosyaYetkiId is null or  
        (
            dy.SiteId=@SiteId and

            ( 
                 r.DosyaYetkiId is null or  r.[HerkeseGosterilsin]=1 or -- herkese açık demek oluyor
                 (@DepartmanTurId=1 and @SubeKategoriKod='INGENELMUDURLUK' ) or -- Kategori Kod : INGENELMUDURLUK ve yönetim departmanında ise tüm dosyaları görebilsin
                 (
                    (
                        -- Isnull(dys.SubeId,'')='' or 
                        -- dys.SubeId=@SubeId  

                        exists(select 1 from [dbo].[DosyaYetkiSube] dys where dys.SubeId=@SubeId ) 
                        or not exists(select 1 from [dbo].[DosyaYetkiSube] dys where dys.DosyaYetkiId=r.DosyaYetkiId )

                    )and
                    (
                        @DepartmanTurId=1 -- @DepartmanTurId=1 ise şubenin yönetici olarak o şubede ki tüm dosyaları görebilir
                        -- or Isnull(dyd.DepartmanId,'')='' 
                        -- dyd.DepartmanId=@DepartmanId

                        or  exists(select 1 from [dbo].[DosyaYetkiDepartman] dyd where dyd.DepartmanId = @DepartmanId)  
                        or not exists(select 1 from [dbo].[DosyaYetkiDepartman] dyd where dyd.DosyaYetkiId = r.DosyaYetkiId )

                    )and
                    (
                        @DepartmanTurId=1 -- @DepartmanTurId=1 ise şubenin yönetici olarak o şubede ki tüm dosyaları görebilir
                        -- or Isnull(dyp.PersonelId,'')='' 
                        --  dyp.PersonelId=@KullaniciId 
                        or  exists(select 1 from [dbo].[DosyaYetkiPersonel] dyp where dyp.PersonelId=@KullaniciId ) 
                        or not exists(select 1 from [dbo].[DosyaYetkiPersonel] dyp where dyp.DosyaYetkiId = r.DosyaYetkiId )
                    )
                 )
            )
        )
 )
         ),
         cte AS
         (
          SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by
  CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@SortColumn)) IS NULL)
                 THEN KayitTarih END DESC,
 CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Baslik' AND @SortOrder=1)
              THEN Baslik  END ASC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Baslik' AND @SortOrder=0)
              THEN Baslik  END DESC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Tarih' AND @SortOrder=1)
              THEN KayitTarih  END ASC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Tarih' AND @SortOrder=0)
              THEN KayitTarih  END DESC


          ) AS REAL) AS NUMBER, 1 AS Indent,  Parent.* FROM EMP Parent WHERE Parent.ParentRaporId IS NULL
          UNION ALL
           SELECT  c.NUMBER + (CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
              CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(@SortColumn)) IS NULL)
                 THEN child.KayitTarih END DESC,
 CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Baslik' AND @SortOrder=1)
              THEN child.Baslik  END ASC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Baslik' AND @SortOrder=0)
              THEN child.Baslik  END DESC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Tarih' AND @SortOrder=1)
              THEN child.KayitTarih  END ASC,
  CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'Tarih' AND @SortOrder=0)
              THEN child.KayitTarih  END DESC



           ) AS REAL)/POWER(10, c.Indent) ) AS NUMBER, c.Indent + 1 AS Indent,  child.* FROM EMP 
    child INNER JOIN cte c ON child.ParentRaporId= c.RaporId

         ),Count_CTE AS (
              SELECT COUNT(*) AS [TotalCount]
         FROM cte
           WHERE (NULLIF(@Baslik,'') IS NULL OR (cte.Baslik like '%'+@Baslik+'%' ))
        AND ((NULLIF(@IlkTarih,'') IS NULL OR (@IlkTarih<=CONVERT(date, 
       DATEADD(day,0,cte.RaporTarih)))))
        AND ((NULLIF(@SonTarih,'') IS NULL OR (@SonTarih>=CONVERT(date, 
      DATEADD(day,0,cte.RaporTarih)))))
      )         SELECT * FROM cte, Count_CTE
       WHERE (NULLIF(@Baslik,'') IS NULL OR (cte.Baslik like '%'+@Baslik+'%' ))
        AND ((NULLIF(@IlkTarih,'') IS NULL OR (@IlkTarih<=CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day,0,cte.RaporTarih)))))
        AND ((NULLIF(@SonTarih,'') IS NULL OR (@SonTarih>=CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day,0,cte.RaporTarih)))))           
        ORDER BY cte.NUMBER 
        OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@PageSize ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY        
   END
```

Comment: Have you considered performance tuning the query? With resepect, it looks pretty messy. There's an rCTE and a lot of `OR`s and non-SARGable clauses in there. I honestly think the SP very likely needs a full rewrite.

Comment: rCTE is required to list hierachically. I changed my sp more sargable version but result is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue with adjust memory on SQL Server management studio because of low memory of db server.

If record is high, then query execution can take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Add OPTION RECOMPILE and transform the non-SARGable where clauses.  see http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

eg

```
((NULLIF(@IlkTarih,'') IS NULL OR (@IlkTarih<=CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day,0,cte.RaporTarih)))))
```

should be

```
@IlkTarih is null or cast(@IlkTarih as date)<=cte.RaporTarih
```

Comment: I transformed all where clauses to more sargable but result is same.